# Removing border from ion-item placed inside a card

Tags: css, ionic3

Hi I am trying to create a card which contains an item inside it. The problem is there is a grey border under the item that I cannot remove. I have tried using no-lines and css styling, but nothing has worked so far.

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item no-lines>
            <p>Hello World!!</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

When I run the code, this is what I get 
[image: get].

I have also tried putting the no-lines inside ion-list

ionic version: 3.20.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add no-lines to `<ion-list>` instead of `<ion-item>`. Have a look at the example below.

```
 <ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let item of allItems">
      <ion-item >
        <span class="text-label">{{item.name}}</span>
        <span class="text-label" text-center>{{item.description}}</span>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Ionic 4, this line did the trick for me:

```
<ion-item lines="none">
```

One can use the same in **ion-list** tag if want remove all the lines from the list.
Hope this help someone. o/

Answer (score 0):

Inic 4 users;

```
<ion-item lines="none">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</ion-item>
```

See the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item) for other lines option in  ionic 4